# C++ Question: From string to time_t object?

Tags: c++, calendar, type-conversion, time-t

I have a program I'm writing to take inputs from the command line or a file with the format:
9999.365 --> Fri 31 Dec 9999
Where the output needs to look like the second part of that example. I'm having trouble understanding how to go about taking a string formatted like xxxx.xxx and converting it to a proper time_t object representing a value. Anyone have advice for this?

I've tried looking up how to do so, but my C++ knowledge is not wide and I'm very new to the language so much of what I've found doesn't appear to work or I just don't understand it.

Comment: I would suggest that you start by splitting the year and day parts of the string into separate sub-strings. Then converting each to integers is easy (`std::stoi` for example) and populate a [`std::tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) structure, which you can pass on to [`std::mktime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime). But note that you can't use the day number directly, you must convert it to a month and day in the month. Also take care to handle leap-years properly, since they have 366 days.

Comment: What does the number 9999.365 represent? Is that YEAR.DAY?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the [stream parsing utilities in `std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock/from_stream).

```
using time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;
std::optional<time_point> parse_time( std::string date_string )
{
  std::string_stream ss(date_string);
  time_point retval;
  if (!from_stream(ss, "%Y.%j", retval))
    return std::nullopt;
  return retval;
}
```

for `time_t` we just then convert:

```
std::optional<time_t> parse_time_t( std::string date_string ) {
  if (auto time = parse_time(date_string))
    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(*time);
  return std::nullopt;
}
```

Use:

```
if (auto time = parse_time_t( "1999.1" )) {
  // *time is now jan 1, 1999
} else {
  // parse failed
}
```

you could probably make this faster by rolling your own parser, as stream-based C++ isn't all that super fast, but if you aren't doing this on a per-pixel*frame basis (or similar) I wouldn't bother.  (Ie, take a string, split it on `.`, and check there are 2 parts, convert the first to a year, make a time point, add on the day, etc).

Adding some `std::move`s would be microoptimizations.  Moving over to a `std::string_view` might also improve things, but stream-based parsing of `std::string_view` is C++23.

I'd discourage use of `time_t` unless you need it for interop with C libraries or the like.  C++'s `std::chrono` time primitives are far less ancient in design; there are a pile of bugs that are difficult to generate with `std::chrono` but are trivial to hit with `time_t`.